# How to make twitter-bootstrap navbar have no color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to reproduce a effect like basecamp navbar in my app.

The deal is that the navbar would have the same color as body background color, and no borders or anything, wich made the feel that 'is all the same thing'....

Anybody know a good way of doing this?
PS: I'm using the `.less` files, so, I can easily edit the variables.

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT: I forget to said, but I want the fixed-top and responsiveness behaviors of bootstrap too.. I also already using tw bootstrap in my app, so, I'll really want to use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ahem, this is easily done with pure CSS, you don't even need Bootstrap for this, neither its CSS classes

HTML:

```
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
​.navigation li {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Of course, you still have to style the links to remove text-decoration etc.

**Edit:**

```
.navbar-inner {
  background: none !important; 
  border: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}

.navbar-inverse .nav .active > a {
  background: 0 !important; 
  color: #333 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}

.navbar-inverse .nav > li > a {
  color: #333 !important;
  text-shadow: none !important;
}

.navbar-inverse .nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #333 !important;
}
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJsfz

I've just made some simple "reset" lines with CSS to remove every color, borders and shadows (at least for Webkit browsers). Maybe you have to modify it a bit more.
    ​

Comment: but I want the fixed-top and responsiveness behaviors of bootstrap too.. I also already using tw bootstrap in my app. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: Then, why you didn't add this to your question? Will update my answer regarding these informations.

Comment: As @t-my mentions, the demo needs the Bootstrap reference updated; Github doesn't serve resources like that anymore, so the link should be updated to a [CDN link](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css).

Answer (score 3):

```
/*  clear bootstrap header colors */
.navbar-default {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm not understanding something but having just dealt with this, it seems like the easiest thing to do is override the default navbar color with a completely transparent color in the alpha channel...

```
.navbar-default {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

If using rgba, the first three numbers represent red, green, blue, on a scale of 0-255, and the last is the alpha channel, 0 being completely transparent and 1 being completely opaque.

Setting it to white would work, too, if your background happened to be white, but this way it doesn't matter what your background is.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap (v5 beta, but will also apply to some previous versions) will mark certain styling classes with an `!important` tag. This will override standard specificity rules when applying css. If you navigate to your page in Chrome and use the dev-tools to highlight the element you want to change you can see what styles are being applied. In the case of the `navbar`, Bootstrap defines the default background color using a class of `.bg-light`. In dev-tools you can see that `.bg-light` styling is as follows:

```
.bg-light {
    background-color: #f8f9fa!important;
}
```

In order to override the `!important` tag at the end of that property, you need to include a `!important` tag of your own to your local css file. Do not make this change to the existing class of `.bg-light` as it could break other Bootstrap elements in your code. Instead, the way I handle this, is to assign an `id` to that element in my HTML and then set a custom css property to override it using and `!important` tag. Ex:
HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="navbar">
```

CSS

```
#navbar {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```